# Writing a boolean to PLC using Sharp7

Tags: c#, plc, sharp7

When I am trying to write an integer to an integer Database field I am successful:

```
byte[] db13buffer = new byte[buffer];
var shorty = short.Parse(valuesForPlc[i]);
S7.SetIntAt(db13buffer, 0, shorty);     
int writeResult2 = client.DBWrite(dbnumber, start, size, db13buffer);
```

How can I write a Boolean (true) value to The database?

I have the following database structure in the plc:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a bit in a data block use the following helper function of **Sharp7.S7**:

```
void SetBitAt(ref byte[] Buffer, int Pos, int Bit, bool Value)
```

To set the bit **Boolean** use the following code:

```
S7.SetBitAt(ref db13buffer, 4, 0, true);
```

To set the bit **Boolean** at position 4.0 the size of **db123buffer** must be at least 6 bytes.